# Invoking classes in Java

Tags: java

I want to write three classes in Java where when a button is clicked in class A and another button is clicked in class B, the two events combined creates an instance of class C. How do I go about this?

**(Update from comments:)**

Below is the event code.

```
// There is a text area showing when it is clicked and when it 
// gets a response back from the thirdclass
...
buttonpanel = new JPanel(); 
getItButton = new JButton("Call ThirdClass"); 
getItButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener() { 
    public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt) { 
        textarea.append("Calling thirdclass...\n"); 
        String result = thirdclass.fetch_message(); 
        textarea.append(" Result = " + result + "\n\n"); 
    } 
});
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Fyi, you can always update your own question to add additional code or details. (I moved the event code to this post for better visibility)

Answer (score 2):

Initialize two `boolean` variables `aClicked` and `bClicked` to `false`.

When the user clicks the button in class A, set `aClicked` to `true`.  Then perform the following logic:

```
if (aClicked && bClicked)
{
   new ClassC();
}
aClicked = false;
bClicked = false;
```

When the user clicks the button in class B, set `bClicked` to `true`.  Then perform the same logic.

I'd need more details for a better answer.

EDIT: Given your code sample and using anonymous classes, I wrote the following.  I don't normally write GUI's in Java, and when I do, it's with WindowBuilder.  Point being this probably isn't thread-safe and may not clean up resources properly, but the point is to demonstarte the concept of referencing the `boolean` variables from within an anonymous class using the `final` keyword.

This worked for me.  If it doesn't help you, I'll need more of your code.

Also, for the `State` class, if your logic gets more complicated, I would recommend the FSM approach recommended by Jake Greene.

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final State state = new State();

        final JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(1, 10);
        textArea.setEditable(false);

        JButton buttonA = new JButton("Button A");
        buttonA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                state.clickA();
                if (state.bothClicked()) {
                    textArea.setText("both clicked.");
                }
            }
        });

        JButton buttonB = new JButton("Button B");
        buttonB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                state.clickB();
                if (state.bothClicked()) {
                    textArea.setText("both clicked.");
                }
            }
        });

        JButton reset = new JButton("Reset!");
        reset.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                state.reset();
                textArea.setText("");
            }
        });

        JPanel pane = new JPanel();
        pane.add(buttonA);
        pane.add(buttonB);
        pane.add(textArea);
        pane.add(reset);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setContentPane(pane);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class State {
    private boolean aClicked;
    private boolean bClicked;

    public void clickA() {
        this.aClicked = true;
    }

    public void reset() {
        this.aClicked = false;
        this.bClicked = false;
    }

    public void clickB() {
        this.bClicked = true;
    }

    public boolean bothClicked() {
        return this.aClicked && this.bClicked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,Below is the event code but how do I go about changing the click event to a boolean. 
 
 buttonpanel = new JPanel();
     getItButton = new JButton("Call ThirdClass");
     getItButton.addActionListener (new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt) {
   textarea.append("Calling thirdclass...\n");
   String result = thirdclass.fetch_message();
   textarea.append("   Result = " + result + "\n\n");
      }
  }); 
  // There is a text area showing when it is clicked and when it get a response back from the thirdclass

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the application, you may wish to look into creating a [Finite State Machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). You can build a simple State Machine in Java using enums, as described [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/07/java-secret-using-enum-to-build-state.html)

The state machine for your given example could have 4 states:

1. Waiting
2. APressed
3. BPressed
4. BothPressed

Waiting has two transitions:

- If buttonA is pressed, transition to APressed
- If buttonB is pressed, transition to BPressed

APressed has one transition:

- If buttonB is pressed, transition to BothPressed

BPressed has one transition:

- If buttonA is pressed, transition to BothPressed

BothPressed has one transition:

- Immediately transition to Waiting

An instance of C is created the moment BothPressed is reached.

As you can see, State Machines require a lot of overhead. Unless you see the logic for your application getting much more complicated, I would recommend the boolean approach.

Answer (score 0):

Attach the same event handler to both buttons.  In that handler increment a counter.  When the counter reaches two create an instances of Class C.

Comment: If you use a counter you have to worry about hitting the button in class A twice and how you handle that so you might want to use flags instead of a counter so it won't trigger on two hits from the same button.